# Xcode with swift 3 hangs on compiling whenever new files are added

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

**Compiling Swift source files**

There is very strange issue with xcode, it gets hang whenever i added new files to it, it take upto 30 minutes for compilation. Once it gets a  successful compile, it work perfect for next time compilation, until any new file is added. Have search a lot on stackoverflow, but nothing worked.

**Fail Tries:**

- Cleaning Project
- Deleting Derived Data,
- Archived Data,
- Mac restart,
- Xcode Quit,
- *will add more and update this list if other patches are tried...*

**About My Mac:**

[image]

Comment: Try clearing Derived data of Xcode. Then clean and rebuild. Make sure you have enough disk space in your Mac

Comment: Have done cleaning too, multiple time with having no effect

Comment: I have cleared my Downloads folder, Trash and all desktop data too. :(

Comment: Have you deleted the derived data ?? Do u have enough space on Mac?? Do you see any memory warning ???

Comment: There is too much space in drive

Comment: Check your RAM size , you may have less RAM size. XCode will take time to load new files due to less memory in your system.

Comment: Hmmm try Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations -> Derived Data there you will see a small arrow click on it. It opens finder with Derived Data folder. Delete it. Quit Xcode and Restart lemme know what happens

Comment: Have already done deleting  Derived Data, Archived Data, Mac restart, Xcode Quit, Its issue with Xcode.

Comment: Can you tell me the hardware specifications of your mac ?

Comment: I have added my system specs to question, please review.

Comment: Ahan!... it seems perfect it should not take the time.

Comment: is it on Xcode 9?

Comment: Yes i have updated it yesterday

Comment: yeah exactly my friend also had the same issue after update. I will ask him how he resolved and then will inform you the reason hopefully at night or tomorrow..... sorry for now.